# How to give single value to all columns of a field in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose in my table i have a field **Normal** for this field , i have to insert same value from row 1 to 100 ,how can i give with single query please tell me guys.

Comment: Column, not field.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Update query like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    myColumn = 'yourValue'
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100;
```

If you want to `update` only the rows which have id between `1 and 100` then add a `where` clause condition as well. And if it is for all the rows then you can remove the `where` condition.

Comment: id won't work if there are deleted records see my answer below :)

Comment: How can i use **LIMIT** option for condition , i dont have id field in the  table @Rahul

Comment: UPDATE mytable
SET    myColumn = 'yourValue' LIMIT 100;

Comment: @SunilSharma:- The manual says: `The documentation states that any UPDATE statement with LIMIT clause is considered unsafe since the order of the rows affected is not define` So do you have any primary key or any other field which can be used as reference?

Answer (score 0):

The following will update the normal of the 1st 100 rows of your table based on the order by (I chose Id as generally this would be the 1st 100 rows added, other options are things like created date if your table does not have a primary key.)

```
Update yourtable 
set Normal = xxxxxx
where ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) <= 100
```

This is more accurate than using

```
Id between 1 and 100
```

as that does not take into consideration deleted records from 'yourtable'.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Ok, but the context came from Rahul Tripathi's answer this was just more accurate to what was requested

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (normal)
VALUES
    (value),(value),(value),(value),(value)
```

repeat value 100 times